# How can I use seaborn to draw multi-colored graphs?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

My graph is expressed in solid color. I want to display it in multiple colors as shown. Why is this happening?

```py
df['activity'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title='Training Examples by Activity Type')
plt.show()

df['user-id'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar',title='Training Examples by user')
plt.show()
```

My result

[image]

I want this

[image]

Comment: try to use seaborn's barplot or [countplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html#seaborn.countplot) instead of pandas `.plot()` method.

Comment: so glad to help